# Ordering of Spanish coastal cities for trip

Tags: trains, international-travel, driving, spain, portugal

I'm trying to plan a trip to Spain/Portugal next year, visiting the following cities:

- Madrid
- Barcelona
- Valencia
- Granada
- Seville
- Lisbon

The order of visiting these cities **does not matter**, but I will be departing from and arriving to JFK, New York.

After some research online, it seems one possible route would be to:

1. Fly to Madrid
2. Fly to Barcelona
3. Rent a car
4. Drive to the other cities (in the order listed above), finishing in Lisbon.
5. Fly home from Lisbon.

This seems like a good plan, but the problem is: what to do with the rental car? Is this plan salvageable? Or are trains a better bet? Perhaps there are better options still? Here, "better" means cheaper, more efficient, or even just more practical.

Comment: Have you considered public transport instead of renting a car? Also Madrid and Barcelona are only a short train ride apart, that sure will be more convenient than flying unless you can get it as a leg on your main ticket.

Comment: Renting a car introduces a time/expense dimension, and and the relative timings at each way-point do not accompany your itinerary. This will reduce the usefulness of the answers you get.

Comment: You have a nice question here and it's a problem I face when beginning to plan for any trip. But the point is you have a huge number of degrees of freedom (medium of transport, where to fly in/out, cost, convenience, duration of stay, ...) which makes this impossible to answer in a way that is "correct" but rather incites discussion. I have thus voted to close as off-topic with reference to the WANTA debate. I am not sure how you could re-phrase to avoid the closure, maybe others have ideas?

Comment: That being said, you have plenty of possibilites: you can rent at A and drop off at B with many rental companies, Barcelona to Lisbon works e.g. with sixt, just checked. Note that there is an excellent high-speed rail network in Spain, especially to&fro Madrid, so you might even consider to fly into BCN and from there train to Madrid to Valencia and then rent a car or bus or train or fly to the others...

Comment: Mts has a good point. There is a high speed rain line from Madrid to Barcelona, so at minimum you could cut that flight. (Step 2)

Comment: Also, if you go between Jan and Feb, the exact reverse of these cities would be better.

Comment: I am sorry I asked a question that is off topic for the site. Still, thanks to all (especially mts and Gayot Fow) for their suggestions. I will look at the high speed train options and sixt in particular. I plan to travel there in May. If anyone has any train recommendations, they would be most appreciated.

Comment: @SteveD, no need to apologise; if you think the closure was premature or unadvised, please go over to META and post an enquiry about it http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: The connections between Lisbon and Spain are not very good, you could also go the other way, use train and/or a rental to visit Spain, end up in Barcelona and then take a plane to Portugal.

Comment: if you are not familiar with the train system have a look to http://seat61.com/Spain-trains.htm and rome2rio.com also sixt is only one option among many

Comment: @SteveD no probs. And feel free to come back to ask more specific questions if they can fit the site guidelines: http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: The train will get more and more expensive as more distance is required, a car is cheaper to do a complete through-the-coast trip, almost 1/6th of the price, tolls included.

Comment: i think @SteveD could rephrase or re-ask the question as  how much would a trip through spain in train would cost vs a trip using a rented car, none of which are easily accessible to a tourist because spanish transport websites aren't translated ( most of them) ,  and what nationals would reccomend. what's offtopic here from my POV is asking for the cheapest and asking us to plan the route.

Comment: Note that Relaxed's suggestion of going Madrid - Sevilla - Granada - Valencia - Barcelona - Lisboa is compatible with mts' suggestion of using the high-speed train (AVE) out of Madrid: the Madrid - Sevilla line was the first one built and runs well. If you decide to use the AVE primarily then the biggest problem is Granada, and the second-biggest problem is Valencia-Barcelona (although that can be done in slower trains in 4 hours). There is an infrequent AVE between Sevilla and Valencia, so it might make sense to hire a car in Sevilla to get to Granada and back, and then switch back to AVE.

Comment: @petertaylor: I think I will end up doing barcelona-madrid-valencia-seville, and leaving off Granada. But hiring a car sounds doable. How expensive do you think that would be?